# What happens to two spherical objects spinning the opposite direction to one another if having the same electrical charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

In physics we know that a positive (or negative) charged spherical object if it was spinning it would create a magnetic field (dipole) having a magnetic North/South.

If another object was spinning at the opposite direction what would be the interaction between the two objects.

1. Would they repel.
2. Would they start spinning around one another at a close distance forever.
3. Something else.

Explain the forces that will develop to both objects.

Comment: The interaction between two protons would be dominated by the repulsion between the two positive charges, which would overwhelm any magnetic interaction. You might want to change your question to ask about neutrons, as these have a magnetic moment but a zero charge.

Comment: @JohnRennie there is a reason why neutrons co-exist in the core of an atom with protons, but i am also mentioning objects not only protons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would be both magnetic and electric forces between the spheres.  The electric forces would be repulsive, with magnitude $|\vec{F}_\text{elec}| = q^2/4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2$, where $r$ is the distance separating them.

The magnetic forces can be found by noting that the dipole moment $m$ of each sphere will be given by the [classical gyromagnetic ratio:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyromagnetic_ratio#For_a_classical_rotating_body)
$$
m = \frac{q}{2m} L = \frac{q}{5} R^2 \omega,
$$
assuming the spheres have uniform charge density and uniform mass density.  (In this case, $L = I \omega = \frac{2}{5} m R^2 \omega$, where $R$ is the radius of the spheres.)

Whether this creates an attractive or repulsive force depends on the relative orientation of the rotation axes and the line connecting the bodies.  If we assume the axes of rotation are at right angles to the line connecting the spheres, then the magnetic force between them will be attractive and have magnitude
$$
F_\text{mag} = \frac{3 \mu_0 m^2}{4 \pi r^4} = \frac{3 \mu_0 q^2 R^4 \omega^2}{100 \pi r^4. }
$$

However, as noted by John Rennie in the comments, the magnetic forces will be much smaller than the electric forces.  Specifically, we have
$$
\frac{F_\text{mag}}{F_\text{elec}} = \frac{3 \mu_0 \epsilon_0 R^2 \omega^2}{25} \frac{R^2}{r^2} = \frac{3 v^2}{25 c^2} \frac{R^2}{r^2},
$$
where $v = R \omega$ is the speed of the surface of the sphere.  (Note that I have also used $\mu_0 \epsilon_0 = 1/c^2$.)  Since we must have $R/r < 1/2$ and $v < c$, we can see that this ratio will always be less that 1;  and for realistic physical objects (with $v \ll c$), the magnetic attraction will be negligible compared to the electric repulsion.

Comment: nice answer, but why do we must have `R < r`? What happens on occasions where `R >>> r`? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#:~:text=The%20forces%20of%20attraction%20field,that%20make%20up%20the%20material.&text=The%20most%20elementary%20force%20between,the%20magnetic%20dipole%E2%80%93dipole%20interaction.

Comment: @PeterDarmis:  Remember that $R$ is the radius of the spheres and $r$ is the distance between their centers.  If $2R > r$ (my mistake above — will edit) then the spheres will intersect each other.  This is not particularly physically reasonable.

Comment: Isn't the model you are referring actually an isotropic model where charge and magnetic are distributed equally to the material holding the charge? Does that always apply as such in nature or is it more complex? Nice answer by the way thanks. So as @JohnRennie wrote in his comment would neutrons act as glue to protons by overwhelming due to their magnetic moment the repulsion created by the same electrical charge of the protons?

Comment: @PeterDarmis: I was assuming the spheres were uniformly charged solid spheres, yes.  Different models would create different results, but classically since $L < m R^2 \omega$, the general idea that the magnetic forces are much greater than electric forces will still hold.  As far as neutrons go, the effects of the [strong nuclear forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force) are much much larger than any magnetic forces between neutrons and protons;  it's the strong nuclear force that holds nucleons together, not magnetic forces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May i ask something more please? Is the phenomenon displayed in this image https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction#/media/File:Nuclear_Force_anim_smaller.gif a periodic one? Meaning the way the animation is done it appears as a continuous give and take of pion between proton and neutron. Does this interaction has certain frequency? Or it is more irregular?

Comment: @PeterDarmis:  You should post that as a new question.

Comment: what happens when you are inside the sphere, inside the radius? In my question i mostly had in mind planet Earth, and only if the atmosphere is considered part of the spherical object (you may not consider it but that is not a problem). Please don't write to me that the atmosphere does not have charge because we may have to change name to ionosphere. As for Nuclear Physics... I have not studied that. Perhaps a model of one force exists and not several fundamental. See harmonics in Fourier transform something like that... But then again that is a wild theory nothing more.

Comment: I wrote harmonics because even light is not a clear sine (i mean the wave part not the particle)... More of a very complex pulse wave... Once again thanks for the answer. Also thanks for the discussion.